# How could i make incomplete color with Container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have the following full simple code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class A2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const A2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<A2> createState() => _A2State();
}

class _A2State extends State<A2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:  Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

well, now my red Container is color full

Question : How do I make some space of the Container center colorless with space loss control like Following ?

[image]

Comment: @Yassin sorry was my bad .. your answer was what i need . please answer it again to accept it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `decoration` on Container. If you need to use Stack, wrap children with alignment widget. Container's `padding` will handle spacing.

```dart
class A2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const A2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<A2> createState() => _A2State();
}

class _A2State extends State<A2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (p0, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                child: Container(
                  width: constraints.maxWidth * .3,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * .7,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 12),
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Text(
                    'some part of parent ',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you lost me . i don't care of Stack contents , i just said that for enplaning .. i do care of how to make missing part of color . see edit

Comment: It will also work without stack, can you point the issue on current snippet ?

Comment: did you see my code after adjust ?

Comment: yap,   I did, try to run the snippet & share the feedback, or  perhaps I didnt get the question

Comment: simply How could i make Container like that image in my question just ignore the text into it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this way by providing border to `Container`

Here is the code :

```
Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'some part of parent',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 100,
        ),
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
class A2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const A2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<A2> createState() => _A2State();
}

class _A2State extends State<A2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Center(
              child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 150,
          )),
        ),
        const Center(
          child: Text(
            'some part of parent ',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

in stack first widget is in background and last widget is in front

Comment: i don't care of Stack contents , i just said that for enplaning .. i do care of how to make missing part of color . see edit